# How to return only one record when there are 2 or more repetitive time data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have 2 tables with fields:

**Working_date:** id (autonumeric), employee_code (varchar (6)), work_date (date), work_start_time (time), attendance_start_time (time), start_lunch (time), attendance_start_lunch (time), end_lunch (time), attendance_end_lunch (time), work_end_time (time), attendance_end_time (time)

**Attendance:** id (autonumeric), employee_code (varchar (6)), attendance_date (date), attendance_hour (time),

Example of table:

**Working_date**

```
ID  | employee_code | work_date  | work_start_time | attendance_start_time | start_lunch | attendance_start_lunch | end_lunch | attendance_end_lunch | work_end_time | attendance_end_time
1   | 12345         | 2021-04-19 | 08:00           |                       | 13:00       |                        | 15:00     |                      | 18:00         |
2   | 12345         | 2021-04-20 | 08:00           |                       | 13:00       |                        | 15:00     |                      | 18:00         |
3   | 12345         | 2021-04-21 | 08:00           |                       | 13:00       |                        | 15:00     |                      | 18:00         |
4   | 12345         | 2021-04-22 | 08:00           |                       | 13:00       |                        | 15:00     |                      | 18:00         |
5   | 12345         | 2021-04-23 | 08:00           |                       | 13:00       |                        | 15:00     |                      | 18:00         |
```

**Attendance**

```
ID  | employee_code | attendance_date | attendance_time
1   | 12345         | 2021-04-19      | 07:57:23
2   | 12345         | 2021-04-19      | 07:57:29
3   | 12345         | 2021-04-19      | 13:00:42
4   | 12345         | 2021-04-19      | 14:55:12
5   | 12345         | 2021-04-19      | 18:05:21
6   | 12345         | 2021-04-19      | 18:12:01
7   | 12345         | 2021-04-20      | 07:50:45
8   | 12345         | 2021-04-20      | 12:59:56
9   | 12345         | 2021-04-20      | 13:00:03
10  | 12345         | 2021-04-20      | 14:58:10
11  | 12345         | 2021-04-20      | 18:02:06
12  | 12345         | 2021-04-21      | 07:58:15
13  | 12345         | 2021-04-21      | 13:02:01
14  | 12345         | 2021-04-21      | 14:52:08
15  | 12345         | 2021-04-21      | 14:52:12
16  | 12345         | 2021-04-21      | 18:05:22
17  | 12345         | 2021-04-21      | 18:05:27
18  | 12345         | 2021-04-22      | 07:44:25
19  | 12345         | 2021-04-22      | 13:05:08
20  | 12345         | 2021-04-22      | 14:57:11
21  | 12345         | 2021-04-22      | 18:10:27
22  | 12345         | 2021-04-23      | 07:51:16
23  | 12345         | 2021-04-23      | 13:11:02
24  | 12345         | 2021-04-23      | 14:58:59
25  | 12345         | 2021-04-23      | 18:01:17
```

In table "Attendance" there are some repetitive rows because employee entered attendance more than once. For example, taking as a reference the data of "Working_date" table:

```
- On 2021-04-19 there are 2 records (row 1 and 2) for "attendance_time (attendance_start_time)"  (07:57:23, 07:57:29)
- On 2021-04-19 there are 2 records (row 5 and 6) for "attendance_time (attendance_end_time)"    (18:05:21, 18:12:01)
- On 2021-04-20 there are 2 records (row 8 and 9) for "attendance_time (attendance_start_lunch)" (12:59:56, 13:00:03)
- On 2021-04-21 there are 2 records (row 14 and 15) for "attendance_time (attendance_end_lunch)" (14:52:08, 14:52:12)
- On 2021-04-21 there are 2 records (row 16 and 17) for "attendance_time (attendance_end_time)"  (18:05:22, 18:05:27)
```

How can I get the minimal or maximun time for getting only 1 time for each 2 or more (sometimes can be 3) repetitive records?

It is only needed 4 records: "attendance_start_time", "attendance_start_lunch", "attendance_end_lunch" and "attendance_end_time". In the case of row 8 and 9 (Atendance table) it is needed to get the maximun time because it is greater than "start_lunch", in the case of row 1 and 2, it can be the minimal or maximun because both of them are less than "work_start_time"

Is there a way for getting only these 4 records and then insert them into their respective fields in "Working_date" table with pure SQL queries?

Comment: Is each entry in Attendance a separate clock in/clock out instance?  And the problem is that you need your SQL to automatically detect a duplicate entry vs a clock in/clock out?  Then I think you need to define that part, at least in pseudo code.

Comment: If this is still in development, I think it would be a lot easier to tackle your question if you can add an in/out flag on the Attendance table.

Comment: Hi @Beweete.

The employee enter his attendance in a biometric time clock (can be in the same clock or in a differente one for each attendance). The data of clocks are extracted an saved in Attendance table.

Can you explain more about your suggestion about using a flag? If it is used it, how it can be differenced when an attendance time it is minimal or maximun according to the description in my question?

The clock in/clock out data is not getting from a system but a biometric time clock and extracted (one by one because it doesn't allow in another way) and saved in a table.

Comment: Hi Fabyc, how do you want to tell the difference between a double swipe and someone swiping out, remembering something, and swiping back in immediately?  How do you tell the difference between someone swiping out, remembering something and swiping back in from someone going on a break and coming back?  I don't think there's a way to figure that out naturally from the data, and you're going to need to either pull more information into your data model or come up with arbitrary rules to know when to discard data and when to keep it.